# Field Service Lightning Issue

Tags: field-service-lightning

I am working on Field Service Lightning and facing some issue.
When a Service Appointment is assigned to a Service Resource(User) that Service Appointment should be visible to Service Resource in FSL Mobile App as well as in Salesforce , this is working fine , but issue is that not all the assigned Service Appointments are visible to Service Resource , this is driving me crazy , if this is visibility issue then Service Resource should not be able to see any Service Appointment , but some Service Appointments are visible and some are not.
I am not sure how to debug this issue.

Comment: Are you using sharing rules?

Comment: Yes i have set Default Internal Access to Private for Service Appointment object.